# How to maintain an access matrix?

Tags: access-control

How can I maintain an access matrix to enterprise's information systems? Most of this systems are specific and not widely-known. So there is no need to have complicated idm-solution with connectors, roles, self-service portal and so on. I need simple application that can contain information about information systems, users and action log. Does such application exist?

Comment: Product recommendations are not allowed on this web site, as a quick check of the FAQ would have told you. nevertheless, I always found that, for simple stuff like that, excel was a pretty goo tool

Comment: I've edited this to be a "how do I" question.

Comment: Excel isn't suitable for many reasons. It's unsecure and unconvinient way to maintain account lifecycle. Special app is better.

Comment: Use XACML or ABAC for runtime access matrix or use IAG (identity and access governance) solutions for after the fact